# Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties fail to initialize for integration testing

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

Using gradle (3.4.1) with an integrationTest configuration, the tests using the ConfigurationProperties of Spring Boot (1.5.1.RELEASE) is failing to initialize even though the application initializes correctly (./gradlew bootRun).  The class annotated with ConfigurationProperties is similar to the following

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo")
@Validated
public class AppConfiguration {
    @NonNull
    private URL serviceUrl;
    ...
```

The configuration file does have getters and setters.  The error that is generated is similar to the following

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
....
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'AppConfiguration': Could not bind properties to AppConfiguration
....
Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanPropertyBindingResult
Field error in object 'foo' on field 'serviceUrl': rejected value [null]; codes ...
```

The configuration class of the integration test is annotated as follows

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...)
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableIntegration
public static class ContextConfiguration {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The test class had the following annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class ReleaseTest {
...
```

After looking at the Spring Boot code for the ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor#postProcessBeforeInitialization() it suggested that the property source was not being discovered.  Adding the *org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test* artifact as a compile-time dependency and modifying the context configuration of the test class to

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

the AppConfiguration class was initialized properly using a YAML-based properties file.

An alternative is to add

```
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
```

This approach doesn't require the *spring-boot-starter-test* dependency and requires that a "traditional" properties file is used (a YAML file will not work with this approach).